# java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search

Tags: android

Why is the following code

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);

Log.d(TAG, "Opening URL " + url.toString());
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.connect();
String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

always giving me the following Exception at `urlConnection.getInputStream()`?

```
W/System.err(16253): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search/access_token=1559619173.3c922fe.4fd71e26225a42a0a03fdd90ef8679a6?lat=48.858318956&lng=2.294427258&distance=500
W/System.err(16253):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
W/System.err(16253):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
W/System.err(16253):    at br.com.dina.oauth.instagram.InstagramApp$5.run(InstagramApp.java:192)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should remove `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);` line because `setDoOutput` method force POST but instagram api work GET method.

You can also check this issue.

https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

The code throwing the exception can be found for example in the [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) github (Android uses that internally).  The lines responsible are:

```
if (getResponseCode() >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException(url.toString());
}
```

That simply means that the url you've provided did not result in a successful response. Throwing a `*File*NotFoundException` is behavior okhttp just copies from other implementations. Why someone chose this particular exception is beyond me.

If you simply put the url in the error message into a browser you'll see that you get a "Not found" page.

Explanation is simple: You're building the URL wrong. Instead of

```
search/access_token=...?lat=...
```

it needs to be

```
search?access_token=...&lat=...
```

`access_token` is a url parameter, not part of the path so it needs to get the `?` as separator while `lat` becomes the second parameter which means `?` needs to turn into `&`.